# stop form submit in jquery blur ajax for showing error

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit, blur

What I want is -username must be validated in blur function and the form must not submit if "username already exists".
Example - https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&hl=en
I have to stop submit when username exits in AJAX in side blur function

Here is my js code

```
(function ($) {
    var u_error;
    console.log('data');
    $('#username').blur(function() {
        if($("#username").val() != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/un_availability') ?>",
                data: 'un=' + $("#username").val(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 1) {
                        $(".user_availability_status").css('color', 'red').text('Username already exsists');
                        //return true;
                        u_error = 1;
                    } else {
                        //return true;

                        $(".user_availability_status").css('color', 'green').text('Username Available.');
                        //$('#myform').submit();
                        u_error = 0;
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                alert('Error while request..');
                }
            });


        }

    });             

    $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        if(u_error == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

html:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
<span class="user_availability_status"></span>
<input type="password" name="pas" required>
<input type="submit" name="r_sub" id="mysub">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like below:-

```
$(".user_availability_status").css('color','red').html('Username already exists');
```

And

```
$(".user_availability_status").css('color','green').html('Username Available.');
```

And

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    if($(".user_availability_status").html() == 'Username already exists') {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```